# how to change the modifier key from cmd to ctrl in IntelliJ at a Mac?

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, cmd, ctrl

how to change the modifier key from cmd to ctrl in IntelliJ at a Mac?
I have changed it system wide but it hasn't changed in intellij.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There's no such a setting to simply swap these keys.
>   But you can load a windows keymap or edit keymap manually Settings|Keymap

source: [devnet.jetbrains.net](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5266715)